# Android Studio Integration with PayPal not working

Tags: android, paypal

i follow the tutorial of integrate paypal with Android studio exactly, but when i click on the button, it does not proceed to the paypal, the system still remain at the same page, may i know what is the problem?
Tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k5lPy_50f0Y&t=1068s

```
public class PayPal extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final int PAYPAL_REQUEST_CODE = 7171;

private static PayPalConfiguration config = new PayPalConfiguration()
        .environment(PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX)
        .clientId(Config.PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID);
Button btnPayNow;
EditText edtAmount;

String amount = "";

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    stopService(new Intent(this,PayPalService.class));
    super.onDestroy();}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pay_pal);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,PayPalService.class);
    intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION,config);
    startService(intent);

    btnPayNow = findViewById(R.id.btnPayNow);
    edtAmount = findViewById(R.id.edtAmount);

   btnPayNow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           processPayment();
       }
   });
}

private void processPayment() {
    amount = edtAmount.getText().toString();
    PayPalPayment payPalPayment = new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(amount)),"RM",
            "Registration Fee",PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PaymentActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION,config);
    intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT,payPalPayment);
    startActivityForResult(intent,PAYPAL_REQUEST_CODE);
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == PAYPAL_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            PaymentConfirmation confirmation = data.getParcelableExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_CONFIRMATION);
            if (confirmation != null) {
                try {
                    String paymentDetails = confirmation.toJSONObject().toString(4);
                    startActivity(new Intent(this, PaymentDetails.class)
                            .putExtra("Payment Details", paymentDetails)
                            .putExtra("Amount", amount));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED)
            Toast.makeText(this, "Cancel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (resultCode == PaymentActivity.RESULT_EXTRAS_INVALID)
        Toast.makeText(this, "Invalid", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That video is for a deprecated Android SDK that is no longer supported, and should not be used

The only supported way to integrate PayPal with a native SDK is Express Checkout via Braintree. Here is the guide: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/accept-payments/express-checkout/ec-braintree-sdk/get-started/

A web service is required for the server side portion of this integration.

It uses a braintree access token from developer.paypal.com (sandbox mode) or https://www.paypal.com/api (live mode)

Comment: Do this mean I can no longer use the PayPal with the Android Studio which from the video?